# Comparing 3 arrays and faulting Null to certain value

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Temperature {
    private String degree;
    private String unit;
    private double number;
}   
public static Temperature[] getLargestArrayValue(Temperature[] t1, Temperature[] t2,
            Temperature[] t3) {


        int size = Math.max(t1.length, Math.max(t2.length, t3.length));
        Temperature[] noT1= new Temperature[size];
        Temperature[] noT2= new Temperature[size];
        Temperature[] noT3= new Temperature[size];
        
        Temperature[] largest = new Temperature[size];
        for (int i=0;i<t1.length;i++) {
            noT1[i]=t1[i];
        }
        
        for (int i=0;i<t2.length;i++) {
            noT2[i]=t2[i];
        }
        for (int i=0;i<t3.length;i++) {
            noT3[i]=t3[i];
        }
        
        
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
          if (noT1[i].greaterThan(noT2[i]) && noT1[i].greaterThan(noT3[i])) {
              largest[i]= noT1[i];
          } else if (noT2[i].greaterThan(noT1[i]) && noT2[i].greaterThan(noT3[i])) {
              largest[i]= noT2[i];
          }  else if (noT3[i].greaterThan(noT2[i]) && noT3[i].greaterThan(noT1[i])) {
              largest[i]= noT3[i];
          }

            }
          return largest;
    }// end of method getLargestArray
```

I need to compare them and take the biggest value at each index from the 3. I tried equalizing their lengths(which randomly ranges from 1-5)  to the same size. Now the problem is that at one point some of them will have null in some indexes. I would like to default them to be 0C for degree, 0 for number and C for unit

I I thought this would be it:

```
for (int i=0;0<size; i++) {
            noT1[i].nullCheck();
            noT2[i].nullCheck();
            noT3[i].nullCheck();
        }
```

but I am not quite sure how to write this method since I have three variables for Temperature. I tried:

```
public Temperature nullCheck() {
    if (degree==""|| degree==null || this==null || number==0.0 || unit==null) {
        degree="0C";
        number=0;
        unit="C";
    }
    
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constructor to your Temperature class that will accept values for your class instance member variables:

```
public class Temperature {
    private String degree;
    private String unit;
    private double number;

    // Constructor
    public Temperature(String degree, String unit, double number) {
        this.degree = degree;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Then in your **getLargestArrayValue()** method, change the three **for** loops (the loops that fill arrays **noT1**, **noT2**, and **noT3**) to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
    noT1[i] = t1[i] == null ? new Temperature("0C", "C", 0.0d) : t1[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
    noT2[i] = t2[i] == null ? new Temperature("0C", "C", 0.0d) : t2[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < t3.length; i++) {
    noT3[i] = t3[i] == null ? new Temperature("0C", "C", 0.0d) : t3[i];
}
```

Each of the above **for** loops utilizes the [Ternary Operator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-Ternary-Operator-Examples).